# Display Count(*) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, count

I want to display the number of rows with the word in a string of a column having "LIV" in it . This is my code. When i run query in phpmyadmin the result shows I have 2358 rows but when run in php it says only 1 row . 
Here is the Code : 
I am using mysqli_* functions , so please suggest accordingly .

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect,"SELECT count(*) FROM w2 WHERE Statut_Cde LIKE '%LIV%';");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$my = $result['count(*)'];
?>

<h2>
    <b> Current Number of Repair Orders : <?php echo $result; ?> </b>  
</h2>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So, is it a SQL or PHP problem you are having?

Comment: How about fetching the results first?

Comment: @CodeClown It is a PHP problem I guess . MySQL is showing the right result when i run the query in phpmyadmin .

Comment: Give a name to `Count(*)` like `"Select Count(*) as count from w2...."`

Comment: @Rizier123 please help with the fetching code in mysqli functions becow I am new to it . thank !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are getting the total of all by count, this is a grouped result. `mysqli_num_rows` gives the total rows, but because it's one row you get 1 as result.

This will solve it:

`<?php
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect,"SELECT * FROM w2 WHERE Statut_Cde LIKE '%LIV%';");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
?>
<h2><b> Current Number of Repair Orders : <?php echo $result; ?> </b></h2>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$sql = mysqli_query ($connect,"SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM w2 WHERE Statut_Cde LIKE '%LIV%';");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$my = $result['cnt'];
```

Comment: Wt u really want? @AnuraagKapoor try now